# DataStax OpsCenter cloud configuration connection timeout with getting AWS VPC and availability zones

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

While configuring the OpsCenter first time and after clicking "Add Datacenter", it fails to obtain the VPC and availability zones using AWS secure credentials. I have made sure that port 8888 is open, AWS credentials work (using CLI) and the timeout is set to 10 min. Despite this all it fails giving ErrorNo 110: Connection timeout.

Do I need to do something else for this to work? An IAM role assigned to the opscenter host maybe? All my nodes and opscenter are running in EC2.

The log clearly indicates some issues with pulling info from AWS, however it appears to be a wrapper around the "aws ec2 describe" calls.

```
2016-03-27 16:28:12+0000 [] ERROR: Problem while calling    ListEC2SubnetsController (error): [Errno 110] Connection timed out10:52:50 AM
File "/root/opscenter-5.2.4/lib/py-redhat/2.7/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in     _inlineCallbacks10:52:50 AM
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)10:52:50 AM
File "/root/opscenter-5.2.4/lib/py-  redhat/2.7/shared/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in  throwExceptionIntoGenerator10:52:50 AM
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)10:52:50 AM
File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 3208, in ListEC2SubnetsController10:52:50 AM
File "/root/opscenter-5.2.4/lib/py-redhat/2.7/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with OpsCenter's provisioning capability as it stands today, including the timeouts you mentioned in some cases.  Unfortunately for now your best workaround is to create the new nodes/datacenter outside of OpsCenter.  OpsCenter will automatically detect the new nodes that are added.  We plan to release much improved functionality around provisioning in the near future.

For more information on provisioning manually, check out

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/install/installTOC.html

Comment: There are several shortcomings to using a workaround.

Comment: ....mainly confined to single region, availability zone, and older cassandra versions. What are other options?